# When is the Crusader class unlocked?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

I've found several crusader-specific flails and shields, but when I wanted to start a Crusader, I wasn't able to. I have the expansion pack pre-purchased already.

Is the Crusader unlocked upon pre-purchase or when the Reaper of Souls DLC is officially released?

Comment: To be fair, there isn't anything on the character creation screen at all to denote that the Crusader is an expansion only class.  All it does is prevent you from entering a name, and thereby stops you from creating one.  On the other hand, every bit of information about RoS also denotes that the Crusader is an expansion-only class.  Which means it only becomes available when the expansion does.

Comment: It is my belief that those voting to close this as "a question about unreleased content" are missing the point of that close reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Despite the game already giving the appearance that you should be able to play the class by showing it in the character creation screen and having class-specific loot dropping already for it, the Crusader class is currently locked and will be unlocked for those who purchase the expansion when the Reaper of Souls expansion is released.